# output result of python program in both terminal and file

Tags: python, shell, terminal, output

i tried this but the command is a python program that has an input "raw_input()"

```
someCommand | tee someFile
```

the output stops at the moment when the program asks for the input

Comment: If `someCommand` needs some input, what else would you expect this command to do if there is no input?

Comment: Is the problem that you're not seeing the prompt for input?

Comment: yes im not seeing the prompt for input

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways around this.  `raw_input()` reads *standard input* (`stdin`) which can be redirected from a pipe, a file, or even another process:

Using a pipe:

```
echo "some text" | someCommand | tee someFile
```

From a file:

```
someCommand < inputfile | tee someFile
```

From another program:

```
someCommand < <(anotherprog) | tee someFile
```

In each case a newline should terminate the data.

Alternatively the python program could be altered so that it writes to an output file as well as the console, but I'm guessing that's not an option.